# Create new page in wordpress plugin which doesn't exist

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

Sorry about confusing title but let me explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm creating an online form in a plugin which allows the user to enter some values. Once they click on submit the new page should open which is a PDF page and their values that they entered show in it.

I will generate PDF from HTML but which page and how I can open new page in plugin as that page might not exists in few peoples's site

Maybe my way is bit wrong but please give suggestion or solution if you know.

Comment: You will probably need to develop a custom plugin for this. You could use a PDF library like FPDF which takes the form input and then generated the PDF for you. You can set it to either save the file to the server, or just display the PDF in the user's browser so they download and there is no copy saved on the server.

Comment: @WebElaine I already created 1 custom plugin and I can generate PDF but how to create new url and html from plugin for example wpsitedomain.com/new_url?some_parameters

Comment: Are you wanting to create a front-end URL or back-end one like an options page? What are the parameters for?